# How to know where directory create in Android using phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

can you please tell me how to know where folder is created ?.i am checking in emulator i am getting suceess but where should i go so that i can see my folder .?
can i check on emulator ?  i am using phonegap .

here is my code .

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      // Cordova is ready
      function onDeviceReady() {
          window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFail);
      }

      function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
          console.log(fileSystem.name);
          var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
          directoryEntry.getDirectory("newDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail)
      }

      function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {

          console.log(parent);
      }

      function onDirectoryFail(error) {
          alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
      }

      function onFileSystemFail(evt) {
          console.log(evt.target.error.code);
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the persistent storage: `LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT`. This means that in the case where your phone has an external storage (SD Card), the `fileSystem.root` will point to the  external storage root: `file:///sdcard`. Otherwise, in the case where your phone does not have an SD Card, the `fileSystem.root` will point to the internal storage: `file:///data/data/$PACKAGE_NAME`.

In addition, you can use `fileSystem.root.fullPath` to retrieve the full absolute path from the root to the DirectoryEntry.

```
function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log(fileSystem.name);
    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
    console.log(directoryEntry.fullPath);
    directoryEntry.getDirectory("newDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail)
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello i am checking on emulator.so first i go to setting then Storage ? where is my sdcard location ?

Comment: If your emulator has an SD Card then open a terminal and use the following commands: `adb -e shell` and then `cd /sdcard`

Comment: ok yes ..i am using mac ..can i check when emulator is running? then open terminal .If there is no sdcard ehich command i used?

Comment: Do you have any experience on websocket? i need to web socket programming in ios please provide some example..?

Comment: When the emulator does not have an SD Card ==> `adb -e shell` then `cd data/data` and then find your package.

Comment: do you have experience of web socket programming in ios